# Macbook Pro Dual Monitors

Tags: macbook-pro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do I need to connect a second monitor to my MacBook Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2520/what-do-i-need-to-connect-a-second-monitor-to-my-macbook-pro)

I'm sure this has been asked/answered before but I can't seem to find a clear answer on it. Feel free to point me to the proper thread(s) and or close this thread if it is a duplicate.

I'm wondering what the options are for hooking up dual external monitors to a brand new Macbook Pro? This is my primary work machine so I want to be able to just "dock" it essentially and then be able to work off the two external DVI monitors with one monitor being my primary and the other monitor being an extension of the desktop (not mirrored).

Here are the options I think I have:

- Get a Displayport to DVI adapter AND a USB to DVI adapter and hook one monitor up to each
- Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter (Not sure about this; is this only for 30" screens?)
- Thunderbolt daisy chain (does this actually work yet? If so, what cable is required?)

Can anyone clarify my options?
Thanks!
Tom