# Dual NON-APPLE Monitors on Macbook Pro w/ Thunderbolt

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt, dual-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Macbook Pro Dual Monitors](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20275/macbook-pro-dual-monitors)
>   [Dual-Monitor Output from a new Macbook Pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33809/dual-monitor-output-from-a-new-macbook-pro)

I've seen many questions posted here about how to setup a dual display on a MBP, and the answers all cite Thunderbolt as the best option for image quality.

My MBP has a Thunderbolt port and currently I'm using it with a mini-DP to DVI converter into a single 24" HP monitor.  I'd like to buy a second, 24" monitor and use them side-by-side.  I've read that this can be done by "chaining", but I'm unclear on the requirements for this.  Is that feature ONLY available through displays that have a built-in Thunderbolt hub?  And, are the only monitors with this feature made by Apple?

I'd hate to get the second monitor only to find out that I am limited to using it over USB and with some sub-par resolution. And I don't want to spend $999 on an Apple display :)

Comment: AFAIK, daisy-chaining can only be done with Thunderbolt displays.  It will not work with DisplayPort.

Comment: As written, this doesn't cover any new ground. Please flag it if it's edited to differ from the question linked as a duplicate and we can see about reopening it.